# How can I create Hybrid App for gear s (Wearable) watch?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am developing application for gear s (Wearable) watch. Can I create Hybrid application for gear s (Wearable) watch?
I am using "Tizen IDE for wearable" which does not show any project type to create "native or hybrid" project.
If it is possible to create Hybrid App for watch (gear s) Which IDE and SDK I should use??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you need Web Application and the starting point for you is an official "Getting started" guide - https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application/web-application-2.4.0?langswitch=en

Tizen IDE and SDK you can find here - https://developer.tizen.org/development/tools/download